# Ubuntu 13.10 2D

Tags: 13.10

I can't seem to find a way to have Ubuntu 13.04 desktop without 3D effects. Does anybody know a way to disable the 3D effects without switching to a different desktop environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity 2D has been discontinued since 12.10 (I believe).

If you're after a lightweight desktop environment, consider [XFCE](https://askubuntu.com/a/65222/176889) or [LXDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/65131/176889) (which is lighter than XFCE).

You can take a look here for more desktop environments for almost every criterion:

- [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/176889)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Unity without 3D in Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10, no.