# Can't get 3D vision working

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, 3d

I have a new graphic card and wanted to enjoy 3D movies, however I can't get 3D vision to work with my setup. I tried many tutorials, without results. Here are the informations I can provide:

- [glxinfo result](http://pastebin.com/QFPiGUc1)
- glxgears -stereo result:

  ```
  Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered, Stereo visual
  ```
- [xorg.conf](http://pastebin.com/DVWrLs5H)
- GPU: Geforce GTX 660
- Screen: Asus VG278H - Active 3D (internal IR)
- Ubuntu: 13.10

Possible problems:

- I've seen I'm supposed to disable composite in xorg.conf, however when I do, ubuntu refuses to start (I get a black screen after entering login information). EDIT: I have tried with KDE and composite off (since the black screen seems to be a problem in unity), KDE boots but stereo still doesn't work, so this rules out this possible reason.
- It may sound like a (very) stupid question, but how is the internal IR emitter linked? Is it done via DVI?
- Did I miss something that needs to be installed?

I hope someone has a great idea! ;)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: This is probably a bit basic, but do you have a 3d-display?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of comments/suggestions:

1. When browsing through the Nvidia FAQ I found that only Quadro cards are supposed to be supported under Linux environment. Link to Nvidia FAQ [here](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2652/kw/linux%20vision/session/L3RpbWUvMTM5NTgxNzQwNy9zaWQvUVNPTVlhUWw=).
2. If you want to use 3D in linux you need to add the following to xorg.conf:

   ```
   Section "Extensions" 
   Option             "Composite" "Disable" 
   EndSection
   ```

   You already have the following inserted which also necessary:

   ```
   Option             "Stereo" "10"
   ```
3. I believe that the black screen after login is due to the fact that when using the option "Composite" "Disable" the Unity crashes. Some details [here on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365332/ubuntu-13-10-2d). You didn't include this line in your xorg.conf so I am not sure this is the case here.
4. An easy workaround is to use for example XFCE besides Unity. XFCE can be easily installed from repositories. Then you select which environment you want to use in the logon screen before you enter the password.
5. As to your question about the IR emitter and DVI you are correct and the signal goes through the DVI cable.

As for the 3D movies in Linux I am not sure that is even possible. If anybody knows otherwise please let me/us know.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe you put a name on the 3dvision in the file by edting it whit kate, and display set that one to sRGB and screen to 1 in the glxvision.conf file, and it might work fine this way, or by reconfigure whit enter this in the terminal:

```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a glxvision.conf
```

and it might work fine this way.