# Turning composite off in Unity

Tags: unity, 13.10, xorg

(Note: this question is related to: [Can't get 3D vision working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403054/cant-get-3d-vision-working) , I'm creating a "sub-question" in case someone could be interested in composite but not about nvidia stuff).

To make it short: I need to turn off the composite option (via xorg.conf), however, when I do so, unity refuses to start: I'm getting a black screen after login.

Is there anyway currently to turn composite off in unity?

Various informations:

- [glxinfo result](http://pastebin.com/QFPiGUc1)
- [xorg.conf](http://pastebin.com/DVWrLs5H)
- Ubuntu: 13.10

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you but if you use XFCE instead of Unity the problem goes away.

When you disable composite the system wants to revert to Unity 2D but that is not supported in Ubuntu since 12.10. Source [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365332/ubuntu-13-10-2d).

I use XFCE and there I can disable composite without any problems.